# Get completion summary for a topic in a module / for a module

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I am working with valence API to get the completion summary for a Topic/or a Module.

I can get all the modules and its topics under a course offering using the call /d2l/api/le/(Version)/(OrgUnitID)/content/root/ , but how to get the completion summary or status for topics/modules (like which all users have completed the topic/module)?

I can see that only way to get the completion details is in the course offering level by calling /d2l/api/le/(version)/(orgUnitID)/grades/courseCompletion/

Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

The Valence Learning Framework API calls around course content were designed to give callers an overview look of the content structure at rest. There is no provision, currently, for revealing content completion data for users through the API.